# Probability Questions like A before B

Tags: probability

I'm working through "The Probability Tutoring Book" By Carol Ash and I've come across the following:

> $P(A$ before $\ B)$ = prob of A in one trial in a new universe where only A and B can occur.
>
> Equivalently,
>
> $P(A$ before $\ B)$ = $\frac{P(A)}{P(A) + P(B)}$

I'm confused why this is true?
For example, consider a standard deck of 52 cards. Let's say I'm trying to find the probability that I get an Ace before I get a King, Queen, or Jack.

There are 4 aces and there are 12 cards that are King, Queen, and Jack in total. Using the rule above, the probability that I get an ace before I get a King, Queen, or Jack should be simply $\frac{4}{16}$. Is this correct?

Something about this seems dirty to me. Why are neglecting every other card in the deck? Is this  principle mathematically proven to be correct?

If so, is there a name to this principle? I'd like to read up on it.

Answer (score 1):

When drawing cards from the deck (with replacement or not), you are not interested in any trial where anything other than Jack, Queen, King, or Ace is drawn, you are only interested in the result of the terminal draw.

The terminal draw is the first one where a Jack, Queen, King, or Ace is drawn.  Now the event of "Ace is drawn before Jack, Queen, or King" is realised if an Ace is drawn on this terminal draw.

Yes, indeed, you can ignore the rest of the draws, no matter how many occur.

So, as it is given that one these four outcomes have occurred on the terminal draw, Bayes' Rule applies.$$\mathsf P(A\mid A\cup B)=\dfrac{\mathsf P(A)}{\mathsf P(A)+\mathsf P(B)}$$

Therefore in this case: $\mathsf P(\text{'Ace before Jack, Queen, or King'})= \dfrac{1}{1+3}$.

Comment: Shouldn't it be 1/4? Since P(A) = 4/52 and P(A) + P(B) = 16/52?

Comment: Does this work for situations where we draw without replacement?

Comment: Yes.  Whether with replacement or not, since the terminal draw *is* the first draw where one of those cards are draw, then you are still only interested in the probability of drawing Ace when given that Ace, Jack, Queen, or King is drawn then.